# Rails 4 - undefined method `call' when doing a simple query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm new to Rails but this seems pretty straightforward.  I have a model called `Game` generated like this:

```
rails generate model Game name:string year:integer manufacturer:string notes:string is_active:boolean
```

I've loaded the table with some data, and I am trying to fetch all of the rows where `is_active` is `true`.  I'd like my model to be something like:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, where(:is_active => 1)
end
```

My problem is whenever I try to bind to the `Game.active` query I get an error. It's the same error in the rails console or if I try to set it to a variable in the controller.  The error is:

```
undefined method `call' for #<Game::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ffadb540aa0>
```

When running in the console I see:

```
irb(main):001:0> Game.active
NoMethodError:   Game Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `games`.* FROM `games`  WHERE `games`.`is_active` = 1
undefined method `call' for #<Game::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fcdca66b800>
    from /home/dcain/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Rails 4+ requires named scopes to be a `lambda` and not just a simple `Relation`.

Change the old version

```
scope :active, where(is_active: true)
```

to the lambda version

```
scope :active, lambda { where(is_active: true) }
```

or even shorter to

```
scope :active, -> { where(is_active: true) }
```

For more information about named scopes and how to pass parameters, I suggest reading about [Scopes in the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Comment: Furthermore it should be `where(is_active: true)` since it's a boolean field (Rails handles the conversion from `true` to `1`)

Comment: @Stefan: I agree with you, when `is_active` is a boolean than `true` should be used instead of `1`. I do not want to discuss the different hash syntaxes here. Both syntaxes are valid and have its pros and cons.

Comment: Two years later I agree with you: We should use the newer hash syntax in scopes.