# Rails 4- lambda - joining nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda, scope

I'm new to rails (and coding generally).

I'm trying to figure out how to write a scope in my projects model that joins sorts based on two attributes.

My model associations are:

```
projects has one sweep
sweep has one finalise
sweep belongs to projects
finalise belongs to sweep
```

In my project.rb model I have tried to write a scope as follows:

```
  scope :currently_available_students, lambda { joins(@sweeps.finalise).group("projects.id").merge(sweep.finalise.finished) }
```

In my finalise.rb, I have a datetime attribute called :finished_at.  I also have:

```
scope :finished, -> { where(:draft => false) }

 after_validation :set_publish_time
  def set_publish_time
    self.finalised_at = Time.now  unless self.draft
  end
```

I want to find projects that are finalised.

In my projects_controller, I have:

```
  has_scope :currently_available_students

  def currently_available_students
      @projects = Project.currently_available_students
      render 'index'
  end
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

```
undefined method `finalise' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Scope actually works on the class level:

```
scope :currently_available_students, lambda { joins(@sweeps.finalise).group("projects.id").merge(sweep.finalise.finished) }
```

But you try to access to an instance variable class `@sweeps`, it's `nil` on the class level.

> and even if the `joins` will be fixed, it will fail later on the merge
>   method, because there is no variable named `sweep` - @Yury Lebedev

Comment: and even if the `joins` will be fixed, it will fail later on the merge method, because there is no variable named `sweep`

Comment: Hi - can you see another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making things a bit to complicated for your self. You do not have access to any instance variable `@sweeps` inside the scope that is why you are receiving this error message.

I think you might want to write something like this

```
scope :currently_available_students, -> { joins(sweep: :finalize).group('projects.id') }
```

Since joins by default uses inner join you will only get projects that has one or more (in this case exactly one) finalize.

You can make it even easier by adding `has_one :finalize, through: sweep`. Then you can simply write `joins(:finalize).group('projects.id')`. (I have never tried `through` on a `has_one` relationship.)

Comment: Hi Albin, I tried both of these suggestions, which seem to work, except for this error:PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...N "finalises"."sweep_id" = "sweeps"."id" GROUP BY id  ORDER ...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "sweeps" ON "sweeps"."project_id" = "projects"."id" INNER JOIN "finalises" ON "finalises"."sweep_id" = "sweeps"."id" GROUP BY id  ORDER BY created_at DESC

Comment: oh, sorry. I will update my answer. The reason you can't use `:id` is that multiple tables have the column `:id` and when you join them the and ask for id without saying from which table the DB throws the error you are seeing.

Comment: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "projects.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "sweeps" ON "...
               ^
: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "sweeps" ON "sweeps"."project_id" = "projects"."id" INNER JOIN "finalises" ON "finalises"."sweep_id" = "sweeps"."id" GROUP BY projects_id  ORDER BY created_at DESC

Comment: Ah, It seems that postgress `group BY` does not work with `select *`. They have a solution for this in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418504/pgerror-in-group-by-clause. But it seems a bit tedious. I shall think about this for a little while and try to figure something out.

Comment: You should be able to remove the `group` statement al together since you are using `has_one`. Or you could try with `distinct` but that might get you in to trouble if you start chaining scopes...

Comment: I tried removing group, but get: 
undefined method `call' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Project:0x00000102ae86b8>

Comment: How does you scope look. Could it be this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338002/rails-4-undefined-method-call-when-doing-a-simple-query

Comment: Hmm. When I go in the console and try: Finalise.where(draft: false).all, I get responses (for finalise). When I try: Project.where(Sweep.finalise.draft: false).all in the console I get a syntax error for the ':' after draft. I'm not sure what search would work for this purpose

Comment: try `Project.joins(sweep: :finalize)where(sweeps: { finalizes: { draft: false }})`. notices plural in where clause